# How to ignore certain input lines in C++?

Tags: c++

Okay so a little background this code is supposed to read through a file containing DNA and calculate the number of nucleotides A, C, T, G and print them out and also do some other slight calculations. My code runs fine for most files except for files that contain lines that start with @ and + in the file. I need to skip those lines in order to get an accurate number. So my question is how to skip or ignore these lines in my calculations.
My code is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
// Ignore how the above argc and argv are used here
auto arguments = std::vector<std::string>(argv, argv + argc);
// "arguments" box has what you wrote on the right side after &&

if (arguments.size() != 2) {
    // ensure you wrote a file name after "./a.out"
    std::cout << "Please give a file name as argument\n";
    return 1;
}

auto file = std::fstream(arguments[1]);
if (!file) {
    // ensure the file name you gave is from the available files
    std::cout << "Cannot open " << arguments[1] << "\n";
    return 1;
}
auto counts = std::map<char,int>({{'G',0.0},{'A',0.0},{'C',0.0},{'T',0.0}});


// Just a test loop to print all lines from the file
for (auto dna = std::string(); std::getline(file, dna); ) {
    //std::cout << dna << "\n";
    for (auto nucleotide:dna) {
      counts[nucleotide]=counts[nucleotide] + 1;
    }
}

double total = counts['A'] + counts['T'] + counts['G'] + counts['C'];
double GC = (counts['G'] + counts['C'])*100/total;
double AT = (counts['A'] + counts['T'])*100/total;
double ratio = AT/GC;
auto classification = "";

if ( 40.0 < GC < 60.0) {
   classification = "moderate GC content";
}
if (60 <= GC) {
   classification = "high GC content";
}
if (GC <= 40.0) {
   classification = "low GC content";
}


std::cout << "GC-content: " << GC << "\n";
std::cout << "AT-content: " << AT << "\n";
std::cout << "G count: " << counts['G'] << "\n";
std::cout << "C count: " << counts['C'] << "\n";
std::cout << "A count: " << counts['A'] << "\n";
std::cout << "T count: " << counts['T'] << "\n";
std::cout << "Total count: " << total << "\n";
std::cout << "AT/GC Ratio: " << ratio << "\n";

std::cout << "GC Classification: " << classification << "\n";
}
```

The file that is giving me trouble is this which is like this

```
@ERR034677.1 HWI-EAS349_0046:7:1:2144:972#0 length=76
NGATGATAAACAAGAGGGTAAAAAGAAAAAAGCTACAGACATTTCTGCTAATCTATTATTTTGTTCCTTTTTTTTT
+ERR034677.1 HWI-EAS349_0046:7:1:2144:972#0 length=76
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
```

If anyone can help me with this. I will be very grateful. I only need a hint or an idea of the concept I am missing so I can make my code compatible with all files. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your actual problem seems to be the standard case of "input is not always clean syntax". The solution is always "do not expect clean syntax", first read whole lines. Then check for syntax. Skip if not, scan if yes.

Comment: What do these `ERR` lines represent? Errors? Then you probably want only to count from one of them, as that might indicate the other is wrong and should be excluded. Which is the bad one? What form do lines take across all representative input files? More info is needed.

Comment: we don't have something like `if ( 40.0 < GC < 60.0) ` in `C++` if you want to check `GC` between 2 values. you probably want `if ( 40.0 < GC && GC < 60.0) `.

Comment: *"So my question is how to skip or ignore these lines in my calculations."* - so, skip those lines ? I.e. `if (dna.empty() || dna[0] == '@' || dna[0] == '+') continue;` Maybe I'm not understanding the question.

Comment: Have you considered writing a function to parse a line? That way you can write tests for that function, and your code that uses it will be much easier to read/debug.

Comment: @Afshin Right, that code isn't doing what the OP thought it would, for sure.

Comment: @underscore_d `C++` is changed that much in recent years that I thought maybe something new is added again. :D

Comment: @Afshin I think there are proposals to change how comparisons work to enable that, but they certainly haven't landed in the language yet. My only other gripe would be not to write it that way, as then you have a Yoda conditional, although I see why it's tempting to do so. :-)

Comment: Since when is `0.0` an int? You have added some code compared to your previous question but not any regarding the actual question. Take a look at the `++` operator. `unordered_map` is faster.

Answer (score 1):

Your actual problem seems to be the standard case of "input is not always clean syntax".
The solution is always "do not expect clean syntax".
First read whole lines into a buffer.
Then check for syntax.
Skip broken syntax.
Scan clean syntax from buffer.