# Read only floating numbers and reject integer and characters (a.b,c etc.) until correct

Tags: c, floating-point, char, floating

I am trying to write a code in C (gcc) to accept only floating numbers  and reject integers, special characters, alphanumeric entries.

I want it to see if `printf("First number: \n");` & `printf("Second number: \n");` are floating numbers with decimals otherwise ask the user to re-enter a floating number since his first input was invalid.

I want that to happen before it starts calculating.
I need a code expample if possible

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h> 


int  main(void)
{
   setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
   setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

   float a, b, sm;
   int i = 2;



   printf("First number: \n");
   scanf("%f", &a);


   printf("Second number: \n");
   scanf("%f", &b);


   printf ("%.2f + %.2f = %.2f -> Summe \n", a, b, sm = a+b); 
   printf ("%.2f / %d = %.2f -> Mittelwert \n", sm, i, sm/i); 
   printf ("%.2f - %.2f = %.2f -> Differenz \n", a, b, a-b); 
   printf ("%.2f * %.2f = %.2f -> Produkt \n", a, b, a*b);  
   printf ("%.2f / %.2f = %.2f -> Division\n", a, b, a/b); 





}
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: "see if ... are floating numbers with decimals otherwise ask the user to re-enter a floating number since his first input was invalid." That actually seems like a good plan to follow. I do not get what exactly you are stuck at. Making a loop? Using the return value of `scanf()` (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf ) to detect syntax errors? Please focus on your specific problem.

Comment: I don't know how to check if the entered input for example in "First number" has a invalid character or Int, thats my problem i dont know how to do it

Comment: Did you read the docs of scanf()? I linked them for your convenience.

Comment: I see i removed it. I'm sorry for that. I'm gonna read the doc, thank you

Comment: It will tell you how to detect wrong input. Then you need to ignore it explicitly. Here is some really helpful info on the topic. Maybe it provides alternative approaches, too. http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: And this (though different language tag) might be a helpful approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62452532/how-to-ignore-certain-input-lines-in-c/62452692#62452692

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integers will be converted into floating point numbers, i.e. if the number is given `5` then it'll be converted into `5.0` for the floating point variable implicitly. Hence, none should worry about that.

Use the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float ask_loop(float f) {
    int ret = scanf("%f", &f);
    float fl = f;

    if (ret != 1) { // if scanf() returns error code
        printf("Error! Please input numbers correctly.\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        fl = ask_loop(f);
    }

    return fl;
}

int main(void)
{
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    float a, b, sm;
    int i = 2;

    printf("First number: \n");
    a = ask_loop(a);

    fflush(stdin);

    printf("Second number: \n");
    b = ask_loop(b);

    printf ("%.2f + %.2f = %.2f -> Summe \n", a, b, sm = a+b);
    printf("%.2f / %d = %.2f -> Mittelwert \n", sm, i, sm / i);
    printf("%.2f - %.2f = %.2f -> Differenz \n", a, b, a - b);
    printf("%.2f * %.2f = %.2f -> Produkt \n", a, b, a * b);
    printf("%.2f / %.2f = %.2f -> Division\n", a, b, a / b);
}
```

Here we've used a function `ask_loop()` which verifies if the `scanf()` doesn't returns an exit code. If it doesn't, it means it has accepted the value successfully, otherwise does recursion again. At the end of the function, it returns the number inputted and assigns to the variable in `main()`.

**Sample Output:**

```
First number: // --- INPUT
abc
Error! Please input numbers correctly. // --- OUTPUT
2.0
Second number: // --- INPUT
5
2.00 + 5.00 = 7.00 -> Summe // --- OUTPUT 
7.00 / 2 = 3.50 -> Mittelwert
2.00 - 5.00 = -3.00 -> Differenz
2.00 * 5.00 = 10.00 -> Produkt
2.00 / 5.00 = 0.40 -> Division (5 -> 5.00)
```

Comment: Beware. The `scanf` family functions returns if they could decode what was asked. So if the user answers 12A for first number and 5 for the second one, you will get `ret = 1` and `f=12.0` for first call (leaving `A` in input buffer) and `ret=0` on second one. Worse, `fflush` on an input stream is unspecified by standard and is only an extension of MSVC.

Comment: You shouldn't use fflush(stdin) btw
_"As per C standard, it is undefined behavior to use fflush(stdin)"_
[source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/use-fflushstdin-c/)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the return value of `scanf()` to detect wrong input. (see [fscanf() documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)).

Then you'd need to explicitly ignore wrong input (e.g. by scanning "non-newline" while ignoring it), in order to be able to take corrected input from user afterwards. This is not easy, see the article linked at the end.
Do so in a loop until satisfied.

Alternatively (the method widely recommended here on StackOverflow) read whole lines via `fgets()` into a buffer, then decide on correctness by parsing.
Skip incorrect syntax, simply by reading the next line into the buffer.
If correct, scan from buffer.

Helpful article on the topic: [beginners guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html).

Comment: you can skip _"incorrect syntax"_ with fscanf("%*s") - _"* prefix indicates that the data is to be read from the stream but ignored"_ - [source](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/#parameters)

Comment: @WENDYN True. I hinted at that in my answer now. Good input, thanks. (I at first misread your input - and still found it good. Kind of a selfhealing input. Cool.)